# Parss error , error in adding html to php

Tags: php, html

I've search here for an answer to this error & I've tried the tips but it seems that every time some work something else appear ,
what I'm trying to do here is to show a list of the student in the database with a check-box for each one , if the user check the check-box the student should be add to the course that he already choose in the drop down list above , here is the code :

```
 <?php
 `$connectdb = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sara') or die ("Not Connect");
 if (!$connectdb)
 {
    die('Could not connect :'. mysql_errno());
 }
 $selestdb  = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");
 $qu = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name FROM Course ORDER BY ID asc") or die ("mysqlerror");

 $result = mysql_query ($qu);

 echo "<select name=" .$course. " value=''>Course</option>";
 echo "<option value=0>Course ID</option>";
 $curvalue=2;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu)){
    echo '<option value="$curvalue">".$row[ID]." ".$row[Name]."</option>';
    $curvalue = $curvalue+1;
}
echo "</select>";



$query = mysql_query("SELECT St_ID,First,Last FROM student ORDER BY First asc") or die ("mysql error");

echo " <table width='40%' border='1' cellpadding='5'>
<tr>
 <td>Check to add to course</td>
 <td>Student ID</td>
 <td>Student Name</td>
 </tr> ";

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox /" name="foo[] /" value=".$row['St_ID']./"> </td>
<td>".$row['St_ID']./"</td>
<td>".$row['Fisrt']./" ".$row['Last']./"</td>
</tr>
";
}
 echo "</table>";

 ?>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what's wrong? what's the error you get?

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your second to last echo statement, you have double quotes within your string and you are enclosing the string with double quotes..

I have used single quotes to enclose your strings and used concatenation to attach your variables:

```
echo ' 
<tr> 
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="'.$row['St_ID'].'"> </td> 
<td>'.$row['St_ID'].'</td> 
<td>'.$row['Fisrt'].' ' .$row['Last'].'</td> 
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first char `` ` `` before `$connectdb` shouldn't be there. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

php instructions should not be put between quotes or single-quotes, remove the first ' after the php intial tag

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong here:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo "<tr>
  <td> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"foo[]\" value=\". $row['St_ID'] ."\" /> </td>
  <td>" . $row['St_ID'] . " </td>
  <td>" . $row['Fisrt'] . " " .$row['Last'] ." </td></tr>";
```